# Query that works in SQL Server Management Studio fails to return records when same script file is queried using SQLAlchemy in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a query that works in SQL Server but not when I call it from Python using SQLAlchemy. I can execute simpler queries no problem, so I know it's not the connection.  For example if my file contains a simple SELECT query, the code works. Also, I am wrapping text() around my query in case that matters.  I'm new to SQLAlchemy and just assumed that anything that worked in SQL Server would work in SQLAlchemy and have read many sites looking for the solution, but many answers might be out of date.

I'm trying to run this by reading a .sql file.  I'm getting the errors below:

```
fetchall
    return self._allrows()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 555, in _allrows
    make_row = self._row_getter
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 1257, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 478, in _row_getter
    key_to_index = metadata._key_to_index
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1363, in _key_to_index
    self._we_dont_return_rows()
```

The code that works is this:

```
 SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Customer_Orders_Daily]
```

but the more complex code below fails. I know this is overkill for this problem, but it's how I have the more complex query set up and wanted to go back to a simple query to try to diagnose the issue.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @query = 
'
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Customer_Orders_Daily] 
'
EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Tried running the first query to test the connection, got results; then tried running the more complex query with the DECLARE, SET and EXEC from a file, it failed.  Searched the internet for a solution, couldn't find one.

**Edit:** python code was requested. Here's an excerpt.  the SQLScript_file parameter contains the fullpath and filename of my SQL script.

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import text
...
def runSQLScript(SQLScript_file):
    server_name='xxxx'
    database_name='yyy'

    connection_url = 
    sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create("mssql+pyodbc",database=database_name, 
    host=server_name, query = {'driver':'SQL Server'})
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_url)

    try:
            with open(SQLScript_file, 'r') as file:
                sql_script = file.read()
            with engine.connect() as conn:
                # Read the results into a DataFrame
                result = conn.execute(text(sql_script))
                
                df = pd.DataFrame(result.fetchall(),columns=result.keys())
     except:
         print("Error running query")

     # Close the connection
     conn.close()
```

**Update**: I was able to get the query to work from within Python using the following code.  The file still isn't working but wanted to post in case anyone else is having the same problem.

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
            # Try to execute statement and commit it  
            try:
                sql_command="""
                DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
                SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM [server].[dbo].[Customer_Orders_Daily]'
                EXEC sp_executesql @query;
                """
                result = conn.execute(text(sql_command))
                
                print(result.fetchall())
                exit()
            # Assert in case of error
            except:
                print('Error executing Query')
```

Comment: please add your python code as well

Comment: Also try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the very beginning of your code block.

Comment: Hi Gord, thanks, I had seen that somewhere but not sure where to put it in my code. The example I saw before just had raw SQL whereas I'm importing a file. Can you let me know? Thanks so much.

Comment: Update: I was able to manually add the code in Python and got it to work, but really need it to work from the file if possible. Here's my code that works:

Comment: Reading that same T-SQL from a file [works for me](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/e9022ec6c443509270a571dd08577d0c).